# Devise and User.create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Usually when we create a model, say `User`, its attributes match with database fields.
For example, if my corresponding database table `users_development` has fields `name` and `score` then when I create an instance of the `User` class I simply type `user = User.create(:name => "MyName", :score => 85)`.

Now, Devise created a migration file including fields `email` and `encrypted_password`, but I cannot see the field `password` (which is quite logically from the security point of view).

While looking through forum posts I saw many examples like `User.create(:email =>"me@domain.com", :password => "foo")`. So, where did the `password` come from? It is not a field of table `users_development`. What is going on behind the scene? I looked through the documentation on http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise but couldn't find any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User.create(:email => "me@domain.com", :password => "foo")` does not directly create a database record with those exact fields. Rather, it uses `public_send("#{k}=", v)` for each pair in the parameters hash. So really, it's doing something like this internally:

```
user = User.new
user.email = "me@domain.com"
user.password = "foo"
user.save
```

Even though you don't have a `password` database field, Devise's [`DatabaseAuthenticatable` module adds a `password=` method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L40), which updates the `encrypted_password` field:

```
def password=(new_password)
  @password = new_password
  self.encrypted_password = password_digest(@password) if @password.present?
end
```

Comment: This is not documented. I guess I will have to dig into source code to understand Devise better. In any case, it will be a good exercise :-)

Answer (score 2):

[This method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb) from devise source code does the trick :

```
# Generates password encryption based on the given value.
 def password=(new_password)
   @password = new_password
   self.encrypted_password = password_digest(@password) if @password.present?
 end
```

When calling create, update attributes, build, etc, rails will try to call for each field the method `field=`, so when you pass `:password => 'foo'` to `create` it will do something like :

```
user = User.new
user.password = 'foo'
user.save
```

Here this method allows to build the model with an unhashed password but to store the hashed password in the database.